# My push on github has dissapeared

Tags: github

Last night I committed and pushed some changes into master in my github repository. I checked (just to be sure) and the changes were there. The contribution was also showing on https://github.com/url_sample/commits/master
Today I see that another team member has pushed some changes. The weird part here is that not only all my changes have lost in this version (that is not so weird after all). I can't seem to find my contributions anywhere (like in the repository history).

Is there a way that a push that has been successful simply disappears?

Comment: You can search these keywords combination: "git push force" and you'll get your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If other developer pull your `changes/commits`. Undo your commit (`hard reset`), then `force push to remote`. The scenario is:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git pull origin master

$ git reset --hard HEAD~1         # undo last commit
$ git push -f origin master       # replace remote/master with local/master
```

Answer (score 0):

To force push your local changes on remote repository

```
git push -f <remote> <branch>
```

To force Push you can also do :

```
git push <remote> <branch> -f
git push origin master -f # Example

git push <remote> -f
git push origin -f # Example

git push -f

git push <remote> <branch> --force-with-lease
```